# Android unable to resolve classes from external jars

Tags: android, jar, classpath

I came across this after updating my SDK tools from revision 15 to 17, seems like there are quite some changes under the hood that cost me a long evening. Figured I share this so I hopefully save somebody else's nerves:

After updating my project would still compile and build, but at runtime throw all kinds of errors and exceptions `NoClassDefFoundError`, `ClassDefNotFoundException` or the dalvik vm complaining in logcat that it was not able to resolve some classes or super classes. Turned out that it was not able to load classes that were located in external jar files (which were on the classpath).

SOLUTION / ANSWER: (unfortunately stackoverflow does not let me answer this due to lacking reputation)

Turns out that since revision 17 of the sdk tools, only external libraries that are marked to be exported in java will be part of the apk at runtime. So the solution is simple:

Go to Java Build Path -> Order and Export and check the box next to all your jars that you need at runtime (should usually be all of them).

I'm not sure whether I should have done that before, but with revision 15 and earlier this was never an issue.

Comment: This is a good example of one you should accept.  Just FYI. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the library Jar files to you apk. Its very easy to do it.

1. Right Click on the project and click on properties.
2. Click on the `Java Build Path` and move to the Order and Export Tab.
3. Click on `Select All` on the right side. Click on `ok`.
4. Re-build the application and try running the application.

Now it should work. Lemme know if it worked for you.. ?

Comment: yes that did work (in part because it is the same answer as the one I included in my description above :-) )  The trick is to not only include the jars in the classpath but also mark them to be exported